# How do I set the property for a custom field type that I am using in my custom list definition?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, custom-field-types, list-definition

I have a list definition that will have a title, description, and a few picture fields.  Each entry in the list will represent a project.  I do not like to use the SharePoint hyperlink/picture field type so instead I'm using the image upload from [Bernado Nguyen-Hoan's Blog](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2011/11/07/walkthrough-custom-field-type-for-uploading-and-displaying-images-in-sharepoint-2010-lists/).  I've got an instance of the list, along with the list definition, that deploys with my visual studio solution.  However, when I go to the list to create a new item and I upload the image to my column it throws an error because no library has been specified where I can store the images.  The field type is supposed to default to the "Images" library but when I go to edit the column I see that the "Upload Images To" field is blank.  How can I set this in my list definition schema.xml/elements.xml files?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two great blog articles on how to accomplish this (though don't do everything in the articles because he tries a lot of things before finding a solution).

[Article 1](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2008/08/12/how-to-deploy-a-custom-field-with-custom-properties-from-a-feature/)

[Article 2](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/how-to-deploy-a-custom-field-with-custom-properties-from-a-feature-the-missing-second-part/#comment-1136)

Inside of the Field tag in your Elements.xml and Schema.xml files you will have to add the following xml:

```
<Customization>
  <ArrayOfProperty>
    <Property>
      <Name>UploadImagesTo</Name>
      <Value
        xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        p4:type="q1:string"
        xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Images</Value>
    </Property>
  </ArrayOfProperty>
</Customization>
```

The only thing that will change when you customize it for yourself is the name of the property ("UploadImagesTo"), the p4:type ("q1:string"), and the value ("Images").